# Express routing and jsonwebtoken, staying logged in after token creation

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, http-headers, request-headers

I'm having a hard time connecting the last dots building a role based access control api in Express.
[Following this tutorial](https://soshace.com/implementing-role-based-access-control-in-a-node-js-application/) and implementing onto my existing program, but I think I am missing the last step and after countless tutorials analysis paralysis has set in. I have since scaled back all my necessary code to what I think is the bare minimum.

Currently I am able to create a new user and save them to the mongoose database. I can see the hash by bcrypt is doing its thing and I can see the token being generated in the response after signing up. However as soon as I navigate to a new page after signup or login, for eg the users own id page`/user/:userId` as per tutorial, I keep getting `You need to be logged in`. I know I need to check for a token on every request but my question is, why doesn't it seem like the middleware is checking for the token or something is holding it back?

Since the token is shown in the json reponse surely I should be able to check for the tokens existence with the next get request at for eg the `/user/:userId` page? Isn't that the idea? Or is the browser just showing the response but I still need to actually store it? I don't understand where it goes to so to speak..

Any advice? Or is this a session thing? I know its a bit hard without all the code but if anyone could spot anything relevant so that I could research my next steps I would much appreciate it!

First this middleware in app.js

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['x-access-token']) {
    try {
      const accessToken = req.headers['x-access-token'];
      const {userId, exp} = await jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      console.log('token verified'); // not printing to console
      // If token has expired
      if (exp < Date.now().valueOf() / 1000) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: 'JWT token has expired, please login to obtain a new one',
        });
      }
      res.locals.loggedInUser = await User.findById(userId);
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

app.use('/', userRoutes);

I have built the roles using the module `access-control` which is required

```
const AccessControl = require('accesscontrol');
const ac = new AccessControl();

exports.roles = (function() {
  ac.grant('basic')
      .readOwn('profile')
      .updateOwn('profile');

  ac.grant('supervisor')
      .extend('basic')
      .readAny('profile');

  ac.grant('admin')
      .extend('basic')
      .extend('supervisor')
      .updateAny('profile')
      .deleteAny('profile');

  return ac;
})();
```

routes examples as per tutorial.

```
router.get('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('signup', {
    viewTitle: 'User SignUp',
  });
});

router.post('/signup', userController.signup);

router.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('login', {
    viewTitle: 'User Login - WTCT OPS',
  });
});

router.post('/login', userController.login );

router.get('/add', userController.allowIfLoggedin, userController.grantAccess('readAny', 'profile'), userController.add);

router.get('/users', userController.allowIfLoggedin, userController.grantAccess('readAny', 'profile'), userController.getUsers);

router.get('/user/:userId', userController.allowIfLoggedin, userController.getUser);

router.put('/user/:userId', userController.allowIfLoggedin, userController.grantAccess('updateAny', 'profile'), userController.updateUser);

router.delete('/user/:userId', userController.allowIfLoggedin, userController.grantAccess('deleteAny', 'profile'), userController.deleteUser);
```

relevant part of controller

```
async function hashPassword(password) {
  return await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
}

async function validatePassword(plainPassword, hashedPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, hashedPassword);
}


// grant access depending on useraccess role
exports.grantAccess = function(action, resource) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const permission = roles.can(req.user.role)[action](resource);
      if (!permission.granted) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: 'You don\'t have enough permission to perform this action',
        });
      }
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
};

// allow actions if logged in
exports.allowIfLoggedin = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = res.locals.loggedInUser;
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: 'You need to be logged in to access this route',
      });
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

// sign up
exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const {role, email, password} = req.body;
    const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);
    const newUser = new User({email, password: hashedPassword, role: role || 'basic'});
    const accessToken = jwt.sign({userId: newUser._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: '1d',
    });
    newUser.accessToken = accessToken;
    await newUser.save();
    res.send({
      data: newUser,
      message: 'You have signed up successfully',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({email});
    if (!user) return next(new Error('Email does not exist'));
    const validPassword = await validatePassword(password, user.password);
    if (!validPassword) return next(new Error('Password is not correct'));
    const accessToken = jwt.sign({userId: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: '1d',
    });
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {accessToken});
    res.status(200).json({
      data: {email: user.email, role: user.role},
      accessToken,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};


// get one user
exports.getUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.params.userId;
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!user) return next(new Error('User does not exist'));
    // console.log(req.params);
    res.send(200).json({
      data: user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Why when trying to post to the endpoint `/user/:userId` is the middleware not checking for the token?

Thank you for any advice!

**Update:**

So far I have tried to removed the `/` from app.use. I saw I made that mistake now, but also tried removing it from the `app.use(userRoutes);` middleware to make it apply to all http requests but no luck.

```
  app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['x-access-token']) {
    try {
      const accessToken = req.headers['x-access-token'];
      const {userId, exp} = await jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      // If token has expired
      if (exp < Date.now().valueOf() / 1000) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: 'JWT token has expired, please login to obtain a new one',
        });
      }
      res.locals.loggedInUser = await User.findById(userId);
      // console.log('Time:', Date.now());
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.use(userRoutes);
```

I also thought that maybe because my server makes http requests in the backend maybe that was causing a problem in setting the `x-access-token` header? So I tried to change the `x-access-token` mw to use `router.use` on all routes but still nothing. I don't understand what I am missing. And just to be sure I'm not missing something fundamental, since I am using the JWT I do not need to use local storage or cookies to allow for browsing between pages while logged in since I can use the token set in the header, correct?

Thanks again for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

That's because your middleware is only tied to the `/` route. Remove it if you want it to be used for every route. Take a look at the ExpressJS [Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) regarding middleware.

Comment: Do you mean the middleware in app.js checking the token? Or, if I remove the `app.use('/', userRoutes);` then how will my routes be defined? 
 Thanks a stack for your advice! I thought it must be middelware related so I'll check it out further!

Comment: What you're doing right now is tying your auth middleware to the `/` route (the very first cod example), remove it then your middleware will be available for the whole application.

Comment: Do you mean inside the x-access- token middleware I should remove the / so it can run on all requests? or the entire block? I thought app.use / then matched for all routes and I do declare the app.use('/', userRoutes);  just below thst first example code. Thanks again and sorry. I'll be sure to go through the docs extra carefully.

Comment: It's all good! Don't apologize, happens to everyone :). If my answer solved your problem, mark it as correct so that other people that have the same problem could use your question.

Comment: Thank you again, after dinner I will give it a try, post my results and indeed mark your answer as correct. I would like to add what I change for others reference too.

Comment: As a test I removed`/` from the first code, `app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['x-access-token']) {` and even tried to remove the `/` from the `app.user(userRoutes)` but still get the same error. I will try some more and consult the docs.